# ¿Cómo se expresa "portmanteau word" en castellano?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, lingüística

Después de hacer esta [pregunta](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/11426/707) me he dado cuenta que ahora sé como se denomina el término "portmanteau" en italiano, pero no tengo ni idea de cómo se hace en castellano.

En [este artículo de Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau) se puede leer que la terminología "portmanteau" o "portmanteau word" se usa en lingüística para referirse a este concepto:

> A **portmanteau** (/pɔːrtˈmæntoʊ/, /ˌpɔːrtmænˈtoʊ/) or **portmanteau word** (from French porte-manteau) is a linguistic blend of words, in which parts of multiple words or their phonemes (sounds) are combined into a new word, as in *smog*, coined by blending *smoke* and *fog*, or *motel*, from *motor* and *hotel*. In linguistics, a portmanteau is a single morph that is analyzed as representing two (or more) underlying morphemes.

En la página web de [Termcat](https://www.termcat.cat/ca/neoloteca/fitxa/MjA0ODM5) he visto que en catalán se usa la terminología "mot creuat" para denominar este fenómeno lingüístico, pero la única traducción al castellano que aparece es "acrónimo", que pienso que no es exactamente lo mismo. Además, no existe el artículo de Wikipedia en castellano correspondiente al del inglés ["Portmanteau"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau).

Por todas estas razones, mi pregunta es: ¿qué terminología se usa en castellano para el concepto "portmanteau" en lingüística?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una opción es "acrónimo", según la segunda acepción del diccionario:

> **[acrónimo](https://dle.rae.es/acr%C3%B3nimo)**
>
> 2. m. **Vocablo formado por la unión de elementos de dos o más palabra**s, constituido por el principio de la primera y el final de la última, p. ej., ofi(cina infor)mática, o, frecuentemente, por otras combinaciones, p. ej., so(und) n(avigation) a(nd) r(anging).

También en [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acr%C3%B3nimo)

> [...] un acrónimo [...] puede ser un vocablo formado al unir parte de dos palabras. Este último tipo de acrónimos funden dos elementos léxicos tomando, casi siempre, del primer elemento el inicio y del segundo el final, como bit (***B**inary dig**it***) o transistor (***Trans**fer res**istor***).
>
> El significado de un acrónimo es la suma de los significados de las palabras que lo generan. Por ejemplo, el término telemática procede de telecomunicación e informática, que a su vez es acrónimo de información y automática.
>
> [...] Los acrónimos pueden componerse de dos sustantivos: *motel*, del inglés *motor-hotel*; de un adjetivo y un sustantivo: *docudrama*, de *documental dramático*; o de dos adjetivos: *spanglish*, de *spanish* e *english*.

Recojo también de este artículo: [De pelirrojos y aguafiestas: los acrónimos o *portmanteaus*](https://blog-de-traduccion.trustedtranslations.com/pelirrojos-aguafiestas-los-acronimos-portmanteaus-2016-09-23.html) (énfasis mío)

> la etimología de la palabra *portmanteau* en realidad viene del francés *porte-manteau* (*porter*, llevar, y *manteau*, manto), que es un perchero, un *portmanteau* era una maleta que se abría en dos secciones iguales en tiempos de Carroll, por lo que la analogía de *portmanteau* como palabra combinada y como dicho baúl de viaje era en realidad muy elocuente.
>
> Por lo tanto, **un acrónimo o *portmanteau* fusiona tanto los sonidos como los significados de sus componentes**.
>
> [...] Muchas palabras muy comunes en el idioma español son acrónimos, aunque tal vez no nos demos cuenta de una vez; por ejemplo son acrónimos «pelirrojo», «medianoche», «salvoconducto» o «boquiabierto».

Comment: Me llama la atención que no se haya buscado una terminología más específica porque "acrónimo" me hace pensar en otra cosa.

Comment: De hecho, si buscas [_ofimática_](http://dle.rae.es/ofimática) en el diccionario, la etimología te dice que es un acrónimo. No era consciente de esa segunda acepción de la palabra. Interesante respuesta. :-)

Comment: @Charlie: Sí, el DLE cualifica como acrónimos algunos neologismos como *ofimática* o *bit*. Pero no lo hace con otras palabras como cantautor, pelirrojo, etc.

Comment: @Charo a lo mejor es ser demasiado puntilloso, pero ¿puede ser porque un acrónimo se compone del _principio_ de una palabra y el _final_ de otra? En _cantautor_ la segunda palabra ("autor") va íntegra (no es el final de la misma), y con _pelirrojo_ tanto "pelo" como "rojo" van enteras las dos.

Comment: En el artículo de wikipedia se explica que "En inglés se llama portmanteau al acrónimo que se forma por contracción del principio de una palabra y el final de otra, omitiendo las sílabas intermedias", cosa que no necesariamente sucede con el acrónimo, de acuerdo a la definición del DRAE. De nuevo wiki: " Este último tipo de acrónimos funden dos elementos léxicos tomando, casi siempre, del primer elemento el inicio y del segundo el final", pero da a entender que no ocurre siempre con el acrónimo (y sí con el portmanteau), luego el portmanteau  es un tipo de acrónimo, sin equivalente en español

Comment: @Charlie: La definición de Casado es más precisa que la que da el DLE. Y en Wikipedia, por lo que dice Diego en el comentario anterior, se hacen un buen lío.

Comment: Doy esta respuesta como aceptada porque, aunque existen algunos lingüistas que no están de acuerdo, por lo que he visto, ahora mismo esta es la nomenclatura estándar.

Answer (score 2):

En la biblioteca virtual Cervantes he encontrado este interesante artículo de Pedro Álvarez de Miranda (Universidad Autónoma de Madrid), titulado ["Acrónimos, acronimia: revisión de un concepto"](http://www.cervantesvirtual.com/obra-visor/acrnimos-acronimia-revisin-de-un-concepto-0/html/01338c1a-82b2-11df-acc7-002185ce6064_3.html).

El él se explica que, tal como ha indicado Diego en su respuesta, los términos "acrónimo" y "acronimia" se utilizan en efecto para describir este fenómeno lingüístico. En particular, se da la definición que hizo de este concepto Manuel Casado Velarde en 1999:

> Por acronimia se entiende aquí el procedimiento morfológico consistente en la formación de una palabra a partir de dos o –muy raramente– tres unidades léxicas, estando representada, al menos una de ellas, por un fragmento (una o más sílabas) de su significante; la primera, por el fragmento inicial de su significante, y la última por el fragmento final del suyo: *docudrama* (< *documental + drama*), *eurocracia* (< *europea + burocracia*).

Pero el autor se queja de lo que más o menos he dicho yo (mucho peor expresado) en mi primer comentario a la respuesta de Diego:

> Suelen señalarse como rasgos característicos, o al menos deseables, del lenguaje científico la precisión y la monosemia. Ocurre sin embargo que, en la práctica, el vocabulario técnico no siempre goza de esas cualidades, ni siquiera –tentado estoy de decir: menos incluso– el de la Lingüística, una disciplina que en la adopción de metalenguaje propio no parece que pueda contar entre sus logros, como tal vez cabría esperar de ella, el de haber predicado con el ejemplo. 
>  
>         No escasean las ocasiones de hacerse reflexiones como esta, pero hoy quisiera detenerme tan solo en un caso de polisemia que me parece bastante perturbador, y acaso evitable, toda vez que, hasta donde se me alcanza, afecta sobre todo al tecnicismo español, y no, o no tanto, a los términos hermanos de otras lenguas. Me refiero al problema que plantean las palabras *acrónimo* y *acronimia*. No deja de causar cierta perplejidad que hoy puedan llevar la misma etiqueta formaciones tan diferentes entre sí como *ecuatoguineano* y *sida*.

Tanto es así que Álvarez de Miranda acaba utilizando en este artículo el vocablo inglés "blend". A propósito de la aceptación de la terminología "acrónimo" y "acronimia" entre los lingüistas, este autor explica:

> Unos autores lo han adoptado y otros no. Entre los primeros, por ejemplo, Ramón Almela (1999: 205-210); entre los segundos, Félix Rodríguez González, al que le parece «muy poco acertado» (1989: 359; cfr. asimismo la valoración negativa de Rainer, 1993b: 39). Lo mismo opina Rainer, quien en su libro, escrito en alemán, habla, naturalmente, de *Wortmischung*, y de los *Akronyme* junto a las siglas (1993a, 87-90, 701-702, 705-709). Pharies (1987), que también se ha ocupado de esta clase de palabras en español, no tiene problemas, porque lo hace en inglés y emplea *blending*.

El artículo indica una serie de terminologías alternativas:

> Para designar el mecanismo formativo de los *blends* se han manejado en español diversos términos: en la traducción del libro de Lang encontramos "«combinación»" (1992: 258); Urrutia habla de "«reducción de lexías compuestas»" (1978: 254); Emilio Lorenzo empleó ocasionalmente "«soldadura»" (1996: 205). En cuanto a los resultados, también han recibido diversos nombres: Seco optó en 1977 (190) por palabras-telescopio (como en inglés *telescope word* o *telescoped word*); la imagen de la «maleta» o el «baúl» -menos feliz, en mi opinión, que la del «telescopio»- ha circulado más en otras lenguas, desde que Lewis Carrol inventó las *portmanteau words*, y así tenemos, en francés, *mot-valise*, *mot-portemanteau*, y en el mismo idioma *télescopage* o el muy gráfico *mot-centaure*; Migliorini propuso en italiano *parola-macedonia* (1963: 15); Lázaro Carreter, en español, *palabras entrecruzadas* (1971: 62), y Rodríguez González (1989) *cruces*. Pero la idea de «cruce» nos lleva, con peligro de confusión, a fenómenos de interferencia en los que entrarían la contaminación y la etimología popular. En fin, Harold Wentworth (1933) contó hasta 29 maneras distintas de llamar en inglés a las *portmanteau words*, maneras entre las que, por cierto, no estaba *acronym*.

El autor acaba exponiendo cuál es la opción que prefiere para denominar este mecanismo:

> Ante semejante despliegue resulta difícil elegir. El término «combinación» puede ser válido, pero personalmente me inclinaría por otro que aún no he mencionado y que en mi opinión lo es más. Me refiero a *fusión*, que Seco sugiere como equivalente de *blend* en el artículo dedicado al anglicismo *paralímpico* de su *Diccionario de dudas* (1998). Tienen la ventaja, ambos, de servir tanto para el procedimiento como para los vocablos a que da lugar.

Comment: Me encanta el "neblumo" inventado por Juan Goytisolo.